# WSO2 Integrator 6, File inbound Protocol process code

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Currently working for a company on wso2 integrator, I need to retrieve files periodically created into a directory so that they can be processed, modified and sent to a remote API.

The problem is that we **need** to use wso2 exclusively and **absolutely can't** code side programs to adapt to the situation. We can use script though only if they are embedded within wso2.

Does someone have a clue?

Comment: Did you try to use the file polling dynamic endpoint? It does exactly what you described: polls a given location and starts a sequence that can process it's contents.

Comment: Yes we tried but we did'nt find anywhere in the doc how to process it's content we could only move it or delete it.

Comment: Docs are indeed very terse on this subject. The best way to get going IMO is take a look on the provided samples

Comment: Take a look at the samples located in the samples/service_bus directory of the standard distro. Grep for "vfs" and you will find a number of examples.

Comment: Actually we've found the sample for the File inbound endpoint. It's the sample 900. Though I made it function properly but it only moves files from directory in to out. It does not process them like a program could nor leave clear explanations on how to do so. I don't know how to go from there.

Comment: File processing is really like any other message processing. The whole file _is_ the message and you can process each like using the Smooks mediator (recommended for larger files) or  regular xpath expressions.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answers! But what I need to do is : 1)receive a file in a custom format 2)normalize it in JSON/XML in another format 3) modify it if  certain conditions are met 4) drop it elsewhere in another directory

Comment: I think I have some code that does something like this that I can share on GitHub, but I'll need  couple of days to polish so it's more understandable. Stay tuned...

Comment: Thanks, I'm waiting.

Comment: Hi, I´m just writing to let you know that I did not forget about your question, but I´ll need a few more days before I can prepare a proper example. I´ve got a holiday this week here, so hopefully I´ll be able to prepare it by the end of the week. Sorry for the delay...

Comment: No problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple synapse configuration that:

1. Wait for incoming CSV files on a given directory
2. Convert its contents to XML
3. Do some transformation on its elements
4. Sends the result to a another endpoint (an output directory in this case)

I hope it helps to get you going (comments inline):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">


<!-- ======================================== -->
<!-- Smooks configuration to parse sample CSV -->
<!-- ======================================== -->

<localEntry key="smooks-orders-csv">
    <smooks-resource-list
        xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:csv="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.2.xsd">
        <resource-config selector="org.xml.sax.driver">
            <resource>org.milyn.csv.CSVReader</resource>
            <param name="fields">OrderId,SKU,Quantity,UnitPrice,TotalPrice</param>
            <param name="skip-line-count">1</param> <!-- Skip Header line -->
            <param name="rootElementName">orders</param>
            <param name="recordElementName">order</param>
        </resource-config>
    </smooks-resource-list>
</localEntry>

<!-- ====================================================== -->
<!-- XML processing logic: Replaces SKU number 0002 to 0003 -->
<!-- ====================================================== -->

<localEntry key="change-sku">
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="SKU/text()[.='0002']">0003</xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
    <description/>
</localEntry>   

<!-- *********************** -->
<!-- Process Orders sequence -->
<!-- *********************** -->

<sequence name="process_orders" onError="fault" statistics="enable" trace="enable">

    <!-- Convert incoming file into a stream of orders -->
    <smooks config-key="smooks-orders-csv">
        <input type="text"/>
        <output type="xml"/>
    </smooks>

    <!-- General Synapse properties that must be set for a One-Way exchange pattern -->
    <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" value="true"/>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>

    <!-- VFS send will fail unless you remove this property -->
    <property action="remove" name="ClientApiNonBlocking" scope="axis2"/>

    <!-- The "magic" property 'transport.vfs.ReplyFileName' is used by the VFS transport to define output file name 
         when the specified URI is a directory
      -->
    <property
        expression="fn:concat(fn:substring-after(get-property('MessageID'), 'urn:uuid:'), '.xml')"
        name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>

    <!-- Create output file -->
    <send>
        <endpoint>
            <address format="pox" uri="vfs:file:///mnt/c/transfer/out"/>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>

<!-- Inbound polling endpoint -->
<inboundEndpoint name="received_orders" onError="fault"
    protocol="file" sequence="process_orders" suspend="false">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>

        <!-- Input directory -->
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///mnt/c/transfer/in</parameter>

        <!-- CSV files are plain text messages -->
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>

        <!-- RegExp used to filter files in input directory -->
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*\.txt</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Locking">disable</parameter>

        <!-- Move processed files to the 'processed' subdirectory -->
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///mnt/c/transfer/in/processed</parameter>

        <!-- Move failed files to the 'rejected  subdirectory -->
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///mnt/c/transfer/in/rejected</parameter>

        <parameter name="transport.vfs.AutoLockRelease">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.LockReleaseSameNode">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.DistributedLock">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileSortAttribute">NONE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileSortAscending">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.CreateFolder">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Build">false</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
</definitions>
```